# AngularJS and Spring MVC - $http 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to post a object that includes an id (int) and a array, but I get a http 400 Bad request response from the server side. This is what I have so far...

Java Bean Object for Request:

```
public class GuardarVentaRequest {

private Integer idCliente;
private List<Venta> venta; ... (Getters and Setters code)
```

Java Object:

```
public class Venta {

private Integer id;
private String nombre;
private Integer precio;
private Integer cantidad;
private Integer total; ... (Getters and Setters code)
```

Java Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/guardarVenta", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody void venta(@RequestBody GuardarVentaRequest factura){
    System.out.println(factura);
}
```

AngularJS Service:

```
function guardarVenta(array){                                       
    let factura = {
        idCliente : parseInt($('#cliente').val()),
        venta : array,
    };
    console.log(factura);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/blue/guardarVenta',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: factura
    }).then(
    function successCallback(response){
        console.log(response.statusText);
    },
    function errorCallback(response){
        console.log(response.statusText);
    }
    );
}
```

Array:

```
$scope.productos = new Array();
let productoInfo = {
        id: $scope.producto.id,
        nombre: $scope.producto.nombre,
        precio: $scope.producto.precio,
        cantidad: $scope.cantidadProducto,
        total: $scope.producto.precio * $scope.cantidadProducto 
    }
    $scope.productos.push(productoInfo);
```

Output:

```
ADVERTENCIA: Failed to read HTTP message: 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could 
not read document: Can not construct instance of com.blue.beans.Venta: no 
suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing 
default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type 
information?)
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@663359f3; line: 1, column: 28] 
(through reference chain: com.blue.beans.GuardarVentaRequest["venta"]-
>java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct 
instance of com.blue.beans.Venta: no suitable constructor found, can not 
deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or 
perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@663359f3; line: 1, column: 28] 
(through reference chain: com.blue.beans.GuardarVentaRequest["venta"]-
>java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

[Chrome's Network Tab Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6C8v.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: In your browser's network tab (right click > inspect > network) you should get more info about what went wrong with your request.

Comment: Did you test your service with PostMan?

Comment: I'm going to use it, but do you see anything weird in the code?

Comment: It says "com.blue.beans.Venta: no suitable constructor found, can not 
deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or 
perhaps need to add/enable type information?)". Does `Venta` have a default constructor?

Comment: My God teppic! You save my day! The constructor was required in the classes Venta and GuardarVentaRequest... Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these 3 things.

1. Add the default constructor to GuardarVentaRequest and Venta.

   GuardarVentaRequest(){} &
   Venta(){}
2. Check if a HTTPMessageConverter has been added to your spring config. Eg: [MappingJackson2MessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/converter/MappingJackson2MessageConverter.html) (Check for compatibility with your spring version).
3. Try serializing the request payload by using [angular.toJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes! The user teppic just told me the same thing... That was the solution, thanks both of you!

Comment: Great! Also, FYI, sometimes angular tends to add a '$$hashset' key if the array is bounded by scope and gets updated. So its good practice to use angular.toJson to serialize the request object.